# Ubuntu logs are filling up with gnome-shell[1968] MetaSyncRing: We should never wait for a sync -- add more syncs? How to fix?

Tags: logging, gnome-shell, ubuntu-20.04

As the title states, my Ubuntu 20 logs are filling up with the below message. The file size quickly becomes so big it takes up all the space and prevents my computer from booting properly. I can clear the logs, but they come back within a day.

How do I correct for the message that is happening?

```
gnome-shell[1968]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x4e00064
gnome-shell[1968]: Window manager warning: MetaSyncRing: We should never wait for a sync -- add more syncs?
gnome-shell[1968]: message repeated 22 times: [ Window manager warning: MetaSyncRing: We should never wait for a sync -- add more syncs?]
```

Comment: Did you found the answer as I after new update on ArchLinux of the Nvidia to 450.57 and also update of gnome-shell and gnome-desktop keep getting the same message in my logs.

Comment: I didn't. Since I couldn't find a solution I ended up wiping everything and setting up a dual boot with Windows. I haven't experienced the problem yet.